# Postgres using powershell - how to tell how many transactions have been COMMITed

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I'm adding records to a postgres database using a powershell script.

How can I tell how many records are in a transaction - or to put it another way how can I tell how many INSERT statements were executed between issuing a BEGIN, and closing it with a COMMIT?

I'm adding batches of records using code something like this....

```
$DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand();
$DBCmd.CommandText = "INSERT xyz INTO blah"
$n=$DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();     
$insertedRec = $insertedRec + $n
```

Where $n is the number of records inserted.
I start each batch with a BEGIN and periodically issue a COMMIT like this....

```
 $DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand();
 $DBCmd.CommandText = "COMMIT; ";
 $z=$DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'd like to do some reconciliation and confirm that the number of records I think I've INSERTed match the number of records COMMITed in the transaction. I had hoped that $z might tell me this but it doesn't.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While I do not work directly with PostgreSQL, your SQL code would have to handle outputting the records changed. PowerShell or the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method does not usually contain that value on most DBMS drivers.

You can check [this answer on SO to see how it is collected via SQL code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941849/847990).